# How to check if all cell values are equal to zero

Tags: matlab

I'm having difficulty checking whether all the cell values are zero. I've been looking around and can't find anything to match the array version.

My code:

```
handles.CheckFinger = cell(1,5);
handles.CheckFinger = [0 0 0 0 0];

if all(handles.CheckFinger == 0)
    msgbox('No fingers selected for recording.')
end
```

My error:

```
Undefined operator '==' for input arguments of type 'cell'
```

Comment: FYI, your exact code works in octave. How about `!any(handles.CheckFinger)`?

Comment: Matlab doesn't like that, showing invalid matlab syntax for your suggestion.

Comment: Ok, sorry, no suggestions then, seems octave handles cells differently than matlab does, and I only have octave to test on atm.

Comment: That is ok, thanks for trying.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error using the code you provide -- runs fine for me on Matlab R2014b, producing a message box. Could you please double check it?

Comment: I just figured it out, I had to change 'if all(handles.CheckFinger == 0)' to 'if all(handles.CheckFinger{1} == 0)'

Comment: edit: Actually this only checks if the first cell value is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, it does work for me as it stands.

However: you need to address the cells, not the array itself

```
if all(handles.CheckFinger(:) == 0)
    msgbox('No fingers selected for recording.')
end
```

Or, in this case simply

```
if handles.CheckFinger(:) == 0
    msgbox('No fingers selected for recording.')
end
```

Comment: @IamTrent  Glad it helped :).  Also -- please note the differences between `cell(:)` and `cell{:}`.  If you are going to use CellArray (which is very useful of course) it'd be a good idea to go through documentation and some example to get comfortable with when to use `(:)` and when `{:}`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it was working for others and not myself but I managed to produce a work around.

```
numericVector = cell2mat(handles.CheckFinger);

if all(numericVector == 0)
    msgbox('No fingers selected for recording.')
end
```

I'm using Matlab 2016a, not sure if this has anything to do with it.